# Read from spring boot jar

Tags: maven, file, spring-boot, executable-jar

I have the following spring boot jar structure

```
- bootstrap.yml
- org
- META-INF
  -- MANIFEST.MF
  -- Maven
     -- org.account.core
      -- account-service
       -- pom.properties
       -- pom.xml
```

Now i want to read my pom file from Util class from within the same jar. The below code always returns empty.

```
public static String findFilePathInsideJar(String matchingFile) throws IOException {
        String path = null;
        File jarFile = new File(FileUtils.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        if (jarFile.isFile()) {
            JarFile jar = new JarFile(jarFile);
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                String name = entries.nextElement().getName();
                if (name.endsWith(matchingFile)) {
                    path = name;
                    break;
                }
            }
            jar.close();
        }
        return path;
 }
```

and i call the utility like following

```
String path = findFilePathInsideJar("pom.xml");
```

path is always null.

Comment: There are no files in a jar, only resources. Why do you need the pom?

Comment: You should use `getResourceAsStream(...)`...

Comment: @M.Deinum i am reading artifact-id from POM.

Comment: @khmarbaise I am doing 'getResourceAsStream(...)' but path is empty so call to 'getResourceAsStream(...)' has no effect. The call is there but i put till where I start getting the issue :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)

Comment: @AlekseiBudiak Yeah but i dont know the path of my pom so i need to find it first. If i hardcode than it will not work for another project.

Comment: Why are you reading stuff from the pom? That is something you shouldn't be doing imho. That should be part of your `application.properties`.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand your concern but if somebody changes the artifact id and forgets to change the application.properties than it will create inconsistency.

Comment: Then put something in your build that places it in the `application.properties` or use a plugin which adds that to the info endpoint to obtain it. You can even instruct maven not to include those artifacts in your jar. If someone configures it like that you have an issue.

Comment: @M.Deinum Agree with every point. How to do "Then put something in your build that places it in the application.properties"?

Comment: You can use [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for that.

Comment: Or even better use the [spring boot plugin to generate build info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/build-info.html).

Comment: How to read build info file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path` is always null because `jarFile.isFile() == false` :)

Also `Path` it's useless because you cannot read it later outside `JarFile`, here’s an example of how to read `pom.xml` from current Spring Boot `uber` jar:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        String currentJarPath = deduceCurrentJarPath();
        Optional<InputStream> pom = findFileInJar(currentJarPath, "pom.xml");

        // read pom.xml and print in console
        if (pom.isPresent()) {
            InputStream inputStream = pom.get();
            byte[] pomBytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            inputStream.read(pomBytes);
            inputStream.close();
            System.out.println(new String(pomBytes));
        }

    }

    private static String deduceCurrentJarPath() {
        String path = DemoApplication.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        int endPathIndex = path.indexOf(".jar") + ".jar".length();
        int startPathIndex = "file:".length();
        return path.substring(startPathIndex, endPathIndex);
    }

    public static Optional<InputStream> findFileInJar(String jarPath, String fileName) {
        try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(new File(jarPath))) {
            Enumeration<JarEntry> jarEntries = jarFile.entries();
            while (jarEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry jarEntry = jarEntries.nextElement();
                String name = jarEntry.getName();
                if (name.endsWith(fileName)) {
                    InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[inputStream.available()];
                    inputStream.read(bytes);
                    return Optional.of(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
                }
            }
            return Optional.empty();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

}
```